# Importance of "H.E." rim designation on MTB to tire fitment?

Tags: mountain-bike

I'd like to convert an MTB with 26X1.95 knobbies to road use for the wife but wonder if the present tire designation, specifying H.E. rims means anything once proper size tires are found. Many thanks!

Comment: What tire and exactly what does it say?

Comment: Blam, these were the stock knobbies on a Trek 800C Sport MTB. The tires are marked: "26 X 1.95 To Fit H/E Rim" and were made by Kenda. Thanks for any info you can provide - I'm not sure if the H/E rim designation is relevant or not to the order of new tires.

Comment: Its just a regular tire/rim.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect "H/E" means "Hook-edged". This would apply to almost every MTB rim.

I have two bikes with slicks on MTB rims. I currently use Schwalbe Kojak 26 x 1.35" on one, and Schwalbe Marathon Racer 26 x 1.5" on the other.

Comment: Many *modern* MTB rims do *not* have hooked beads, and road and gravel carbon rims may be trending in this direction also. I don't think hookless was a thing during the era when 26" was the main MTB wheel size, though. And if someone happened across a good 26" tire compatible with hookless rims, you can still mount that to a rim with bead hooks. The *reverse* isn't true, i.e. if you have a hookless rim and your tires explicitly state they are *not* hookless compatible, don't use the tires.

Comment: Gravel bikes weren't even a thing 5.5 years ago...

Answer (score -3):

***H.E.*** doesn't mean anything. It's a marketing gimmick.

I think it helps the tire manufacturer to justify the high prices they charge for a simple bicycle tire.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. We're looking for answers with [more detail](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Please consider editing your answer to explain why you believe that the H.E. designation is a way for manufacturers to justify high prices. A short, one-line answer like this is likely to get downvoted, flagged for moderator intervention, and possibly deleted.

Comment: We are also looking for answers, and this is not really an answer.

Comment: @WeiwenNg I think it's an answer. Effectively, it says "H.E. doesn't mean anything. It's a marketing gimmick." While it needs support, it's an answer.

Comment: I feel your pain.  A decent bike tyre costs as much as a simple passenger car tyre, but there's 6-12 kg in each one, and a bike tyre is under 250g for a GP5000 or 1.2 kg for a heavy MTB tyre.  But cars need 4 and there's a lot more car tyres on the road than bicycle tyres, so market volumes helps drive prices down.

Comment: After doing some research, HE does absolutely mean something important.  Hooked Edge, synonymous with Clincher, Crochet Hook.    This is literally how the tyre's bead secures to the rim, so getting a matching tyre is important for tyre retention.  Opposite to "tubular" which is glued or taped to the rim with special adhesives.   On the positive side, most tyres that aren't tubeless or tubular are hooked bead and will work.  Getting it wrong would be a safety risk for the rider.